# $\aleph_1$-complete fine measures on $P_\kappa(\lambda)$

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

**Definition**  A  fine measure on $P_\kappa(\lambda)$ is a non-principal ultrafilter on $P_\kappa(\lambda)$ which contains all upper cones $\uparrow{x}=\{y\in P_\kappa(\lambda)|x\subset y\}$, for all $x\in P_\kappa(\lambda)$.

Bagaria and Magidor defined a cardinal $\kappa$ to be $\aleph_1$-strongly compact if there exists a non-principal $\aleph_1$-complete fine measure on $P_\kappa(\lambda)$, for all $\lambda\ge\kappa$. This is a refinement of the usual definition of strongly compacts where $\kappa$-completeness has been relaxed to $\aleph_1$-completeness.

I want to further relax the assumption that all upper cones belong to $U$.

**Definition** Let $F$ be a subset of $\lambda$ (which maybe empty).
An ultrafilter on $P_\kappa(\lambda)$ is $F$-fine if for every $a\in \lambda$, $\uparrow{\{a\}}\in U$ if and only if $a\in F$.
If $F=\lambda$ then we recover the definition of a fine measure.

**Question**
Assume $\kappa$ is an $\aleph_1$-strongly compact cardinal. Let $F\subset \lambda$ be of size $<\lambda$. Can we prove there is a non-principal $F$-fine $\aleph_1$-complete ultrafilter on $P_\kappa(\lambda)$?

Comment: The definition of $F$-fineness seems restrictive with the "if *and only if*"...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, it is very restrictive. We want "total control"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if $F$ is large enough.  Let $j : V \to M$ be the embedding derived from an $\aleph_1$-strongly compact ultrafilter $U$ on $P_\kappa(\lambda)$.  Let $[\mathrm{id}]$ be the set in $M$ represented by the identity function.  Define $W \subseteq P(P_\kappa(\lambda))$ by:
$$A \in W \Leftrightarrow [\mathrm{id}] \cap j(F) \in j(A).$$

Then $W$ is a countably complete ultrafilter.  If $\alpha \in F$, then $j(\alpha) \in [\mathrm{id}] \cap j(F)$, so $[\mathrm{id}] \cap j(F) \in j({\uparrow}\{\alpha\})$.  If $\alpha\notin F$, then $j(\alpha) \notin j(F)$, so $[\mathrm{id}] \cap j(F) \notin j({\uparrow}\{\alpha\})$.  Thus $W$ is $F$-fine.

It remains to check that $W$ is nonprincipal.  This holds when $|F| \geq \kappa$.  To see this, suppose on the contrary that there is $z_0$ such that $A \in W$ iff $z_0 \in A$.  Then $[\mathrm{id}] \cap j(F) = j(z_0)$.  But $|[\mathrm{id}] \cap j(F)| \geq |j[\lambda] \cap j(F)| \geq j(\kappa)$, which means $|z_0| \geq \kappa$, which is false.

On the other hand, if $|F|<\mathrm{crit}(j)$, then $j(F) = j[F] = [\mathrm{id}] \cap j[F]$, so $A \in W$ iff $j(F) \in j(A)$, thus $A \in W$ iff $F \in A$.  In this case, $W$ is principal.

I'm not sure what happens when $\mathrm{crit}(j) \leq |F| < \kappa$.

Comment: @IoannisSouldatos $\mathrm{crit}(j)$ must be a large cardinal, since it is the completness of some countably complete ultrafilter.  I edited my answer to reflect what I didn't figure out.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mistake. $crit(j)$ is at least the first measurable. I deleted my comment. The question for small $F$ remains.

Comment: You can make $W$ nonprincipal by deriving instead from $\sigma = [\text{id}]\cap j(F)\cup \{\alpha\}$ where $\alpha < j(\lambda)$ does not belong to $j(A)$ for any $A$ with $|A| < \kappa$. The $F$-fineness argument is the same. To see $W$ is nonprincipal, we need that $\sigma\notin \text{ran}(j)$. If $|\sigma|\geq \kappa$, $\sigma\notin \text{ran}(j)$ since otherwise $|\sigma|$ would be in $\text{ran}(j)$ but no cardinal between $\kappa$ and $j(\kappa)$ is. If $|\sigma| < \kappa$, assume towards a contradiction that $\sigma = j(A)$. Then $|A| < \kappa$ but $\alpha\in j(A)$, contradiction.

Comment: If $\kappa < \lambda$, then such an ordinal $\alpha$ exists, namely $\alpha = \sup j[\kappa^+]$. If $\kappa = \lambda$, there is an issue when $\kappa$ is singular. Then one must be more careful about the choice of $U$. But (assuming now $\kappa$ is the least $\aleph_1$-strongly compact without loss of generality) one can choose $U$ to be a uniform $\aleph_1$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$, viewed an ultrafilter on $P_\kappa(\kappa)$ concentrating on ordinals. Take $\alpha = [\text{id}]_U$. The existence of $U$ is not too hard to prove, although it is not immediate from the definition.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg Thanks for your comments. Can you explain why $\sup j[\kappa^+]$ is not in $j(A)$ for $|A|<\kappa$?

Comment: @GabeGoldberg If I understand you correctly, [id] is computed using an $\aleph_1$-complete ultrafilter on $P_\kappa(\lambda)$ and $a$ is computed using a different ultrafilter on (the atoms of) $P_\kappa(\lambda)$ .

Comment: @IoannisSouldatos When you say $a$, do you mean $\alpha$? I'm not sure what you mean by computed, it's just some ordinal. The context I intended was Monroe's answer, so $j:V\to M$ is the elementary embedding associated to an $\aleph_1$-complete ultrafilter $U$ on $P_\kappa(\lambda)$ and we are trying to use it to define an $F$-fine ultrafilter $W$.

Comment: @MonroeEskew This is equivalent to the fact that the ultrafilter on $\kappa^+$ derived from $j$ using $\sup j[\kappa^+]$ is uniform. Concretely, fix $A$ with $|A| \leq \kappa$. Note that $j(\kappa^+) > \sup j[\kappa^+]$ since [id] witnesses $\text{cf}^M(\sup j[\kappa^+]) < j(\kappa)$ whereas $j(\kappa^+)$ is regular in $M$. So to show $\sup j[\kappa^+]\notin j(A)$, it suffices to show that $\sup j[\kappa^+]\notin j(A\cap \kappa^+)$, which is obvious since $A\cap \kappa^+$ is bounded below some $\beta < \kappa^+$ and so $j(A\cap \kappa^+)\subseteq j(\beta) < \sup j[\kappa^+]$.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg Yes, a should be $\alpha$. "Computed" means that $[id]$ is an equivalence class which depends on the specific ultrafilter. My question is in the case $\kappa=\lambda$. You take $\alpha$ to be $[id]$ again, but this time the ultrafilter is different than the first occurrence of $[id]$.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg You don't assume anything on the cardinality of $F$?

Comment: @IoannisSouldatos Actually I intend for $U$ to be the same ultrafilter. The point I was trying to make was that in the singular case, one has to make some assumptions about the ultrafilter $U$ on $P_\kappa(\kappa)$ you start out with: namely, that it concentrates on $\kappa$ and is uniform. In this case, the cover [id] of $j[\kappa]$ is an ordinal $\alpha < j(\kappa)$, and the $F$-fine ultrafilter $W$ one obtains is the ultrafilter on $P_\kappa(\kappa)$ derived from $j$ using $(\alpha\cap j(F))\cup \{\alpha\}$.

Comment: @IoannisSouldatos No, I am suggesting an extension of Monroe's idea that will give $F$-fine ultrafilters on $P_\kappa(\lambda)$ for arbitrary $F\subseteq \lambda$ if $\kappa$ is the least $\omega_1$-strongly compact.

Comment: I just noticed that someone downvoted this answer. I do not see a reason for this, but who downvoted can explain what is wrong with this answer.

Comment: I think Eskew's answer together with Goldberg's comments answer my question. I will accept.